# How to delete some nodes on AWS ElasticSearch cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I'm trying to change my AWS ElasticSearch nodes to lower configuration. But when I do this, it adds more nodes to the original cluster. I can't delete them. And I search on Google, everybody says I have to delete the domain. But this may let me lose all indexes I built on it, right?
Is there any way that I can delete some nodes but remain the others?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply change the number of nodes in your ElasticSearch domain (Note: your data must fit into smaller amount of nodes)

The number of nodes visible in CloudWatch metrics can be misleading and AWS points this fact in [ElasticSearch documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html):

> Note
>
> The Nodes metric is not accurate during changes to your cluster
>   configuration and during routine maintenance for the service. This is
>   expected behavior. The metric will report the correct number of
>   cluster nodes soon.

I actually tried to simulate what you want to do.

1. I created ES domain with 4 nodes
2. Once the domain was created, I changed the number of nodes to 2

When looking at nodes count metric, I could see that temporarily the amount of nodes in the ES domain was 6, but eventually went down to 2.

[image]

In case when number of nodes does not stabilize for a long time, I recommend contacting AWS.

Comment: was that done from  AWS UI or using the AWS CLI ? Because i am sure UI we can reduce the number of nodes but from  the CLI i don't see a command to reduce nodes. If you are aware of it can you please share

Comment: Both work. update-elasticsearch-domain-config is AWS CLI command you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, i tried with lesser number node and it worked.